Querying the last N partitions from S3 external table efficiently using Redshift SQL
is there any way how to select the last N (e.g. 3) S3 external table partitions dynamically and efficiently rather than using:
SELECT TOP 3 DISTINCT EFF_DT FROM DL.FACT_SALES WHERE EFF_DT <= P_EFF_DT ORDER BY EFF_DT DESC

Assume the following external table containing tens of millions rows per partition:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE DL.FACT_SALES (
    id string,
    amt bigint,
    sale_dt timestamp
) PARTITION BY (eff_dt timestamp)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://my_bucket/path/fact_sales/'

The SQL aforementioned query runs for several minutes with such data volumes and it does a lot of unnecessary work (like going through each row, etc.). Is there any way how to speed up such query? Is it a good idea to rely on any meta-data view i.e. SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS? Would such approach also work with multiple availability zones? Thanks!
